# Laurent series of real part of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

In the book "Harmonic function theory" p. 9 there is this claim: let $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_jz^j$ be a holomorphic function. Then its real part takes the form
\begin{equation}
u(r\xi)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_jr^{|j|}\xi^j,\qquad for \ 0<r<1, |\xi|=1.
\end{equation}
It does not convince me, here is my attempt. 
Write $u(z)=\dfrac{f+\overline{f}}{2}(z)$ and $\xi=e^{it}$, then
$$
f(re^{it})=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_jr^je^{ijt}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{|j|}r^{|j|}e^{ijt}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_{|j|}r^{|j|}\xi^j
$$
and
$$
\overline{f}(re^{it})=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\overline{a}_jr^je^{-ijt}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}\overline{a}_{|k|}r^{|k|}e^{ikt}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}\overline{a}_{|k|}r^{|k|}\xi^k,
$$
but the equality does not follow.

Comment: Should that be $a_{|j|}$?

Comment: Do you mean in the book? I really though that, perhaps it is a typo.

Comment: Does it say anything about a convention for what $a_j$ means for negative $j$ when $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: Nothing, $f$ is just any holomorphic function.

Comment: But $u(r\xi)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_jr^{|j|}\xi^j$ makes no sense because $a_j$ is not defined for $j< 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They never wrote $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_jz^j.$

Instead, let$$f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}b_jz^j.$$
Then,
$$u(r\zeta)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_jr^{|j|}\zeta^j\quad \text{ for }\quad 0\le r<1, |\zeta|=1$$
where
$$a_j=\begin{cases}\frac{b_j}2&\text{if }j>0\\\frac{\overline{b_{-j}}}2&\text{if }j<0\\\frac{b_0+\overline{b_0}}2&\text{if }j=0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed the $a_j$ to be the coefficient of the original function, but it is not true. Thank you!